# Создание массива из множества полей

Tags: php, массивы, wordpress

Есть задача построить массив такого типа:

```
array{  
    array(0){подпись => 'description', ссылка => 'link'}
    array(1){подпись1 => 'description', ссылка1 => 'link'}
    array(2){подпись2 => 'description', ссылка2 => 'link'}
}
```

из `n` множества таких полей:

```
<div class="inputs">
    <div>
        <input type="text" size="50" name="description_file[]" value="<?php echo $value_d_files; ?>" /> Подпись к ссылке
        <br>
        <input id="upload_image0" type="text" size="50" name="link_file[]" value="<?php echo $value_d_files; ?>" /> 
        <input id="upload_image_button0" class="button up_img_but" type="button" value="Загрузить новый файл" />
    </div>
</div>
```

После `submit` получается два массива:

```
array ([0]=Array([0]=>подпись, [1]=>подпись1, [2]=>подпись2)
array ([0]=Array([0]=>ссылка, [1]=>ссылка1, [2]=>ссылка2)
```

Как их привести в нужный мне вид?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$resultArray = array();
foreach($array1 AS $i=>$item1) {
    $resultArray[$i] = array(
        'description' => $item1,
        'link' => $array2[$i]
    );
}
```

Где *$array1* и *$array2* -- ваши два ненужных массива

**Обновление**

Самый изящный способ, если немного поменять условие задачи:

```
$resultArray = array_combine($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Хорошо, а как сделать более изящно?

Comment: ^ только очень сильно надо поменять условие :)